# JQuery onclick do something ... after click alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code:

`onclick="$('#default').click();"` ... is there any way to return an alert of something if it's done sucessfully?

Update:

There seems to be a proble here:

```
onclick="$('#default').click( function() { alert('clicked'); });"
```

Comment: you can use .click(function { alert('worked'); }) .

Comment: a jsfiddle example and a bit in-depth explanation would be nice

Comment: Not sure why you're using code like that. Using jQuery you don't need to use the `onClick` method within elements anymore. If you're using jQuery you can do it all from the javascript using event binders and handlers.

Comment: @Thomas I assume you meant the [`onclick` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onclick) of DOM elements? There's nothing magical about jQuery, though. It just wraps around the plain old [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener).

Comment: @Satch3000: can you explain what you're trying to do? Do you want to respond to `#default` being clicked? What is it that is supposed to be  "done successfully" before the `alert()`?

Comment: @PPVG yeah, sorry for my bad syntax. I know there's nothing "magical" about jQuery, however if you're going to use it then there's little point still using `onClick` in elements. Putting code inline like in the OP is hard to read and hard to maintain, plus goes against the separation of function that jQuery does so well at maintaining e.g. js is separate from html is separate from css etc.

Comment: @Thomas I agree wholeheartedly. :-)

Answer (score 13):

That syntax is a bit off. Usually you'd use jQuery's `click()` like this:

> HTML:
>
> ```
> <a id="something">Text</a>
> ```

> JavaScript:
>
> ```
> $('#something').click( function() { alert('clicked'); });
> ```

Update:

Even your updated code seems to work, but it is very bad code like that - you might have some error somewhere else in your javascript, or in the DOM structure. See http://jsfiddle.net/HCQeN/1/

It would be much better to seperate the jquery from the onclick, like: http://jsfiddle.net/ctUgp/

Comment: unless `#default` is another element he wants to trigger a click on when his original element is clicked

Comment: even still, there's no reason not to use pure jquery and not put javscript within the `onClick` attribute of elements.

Comment: @Thomas: what are you trying to say? Your statement is ambiguous. If using jQuery is `A` and using pure JS is `B`, are you saying `¬(¬A ∧ ¬B)` or do you mean `¬(¬A) ∧ ¬B`? The latter would make more sense, but I still wouldn't see your point.

Comment: lol quite confused @PPvG. @kontur seems to be saying what I am saying in other comments and answers which is that he would separate the element from the jQuery and us an event handler in jQuery to catch onClick events. Nav appeared to challenge this in his comment. I was merely pointing out that even if the OP wants to trigger a click event on another element then this can still be achieved using jquery separate to the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: @Thomas, what @nav referred to was triggering the `click` event to be **fired** on **another** element, by calling `.click()` without any arguments. Which is a valid remark, but no longer relevant since the OP updated their question.

Answer (score 3):

Lets say your example is:

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" onClick="$('#default').click()" />
```

What you want is:

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" />

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  // this code will run when the document has loaded
  // and all elements are in place

  $("#myButton").click(function(){
    // this code will be run when the user clicks on
    // the button we created above

    $('#default').click(); // this calls the click event on #default

    alert('Finished'); // now it is finished
  }); // close the click handler on #myButton

  $('#default').click(function(){
    // this code will be run when the user click on
    // the element with id "default" OR (in this case)
    // when the click event is triggered from clicking the
    // button above.

    alert('#default was clicked');
  }); // close the click handler on #default

}); // close the document.ready code block.

</script>
```

Comment: I wanted to do this inline in the onclick so there's less code involved.

Comment: I understand. However its bad practice to do so. Its much better to keep javascript and HTML code separate. That way its much easier to maintain and much less difficult to debug and such. Personally I think its better to use a little bit more code and then you have something that is easy to maintain and build upon. See http://jsfiddle.net/JQrNv/ <-- its not REALLY that much more code.

Answer (score 2):

just like this

```
$('#default').click( function() {
  alert('Handler for .click() called.');
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
onclick="$('#default').click(function() { alert('foobar'); });"
```